# Problem with Method reference operator and CompileStatic

Tags: groovy, method-reference, compile-static

In the following code, `@CompileStatic` does not work in combination with the [method reference operator](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-reference-operator) for Groovy methods `collect` and `find`, although it works with Java streams or the [method pointer operator](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator). Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported?

The code does not compile using Java 17 and Groovy 4.0.15.

```groovy
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
private void groovyFuncWithMethodPointer(int n) {
    // works
    def res = (1..n).collect(this.&calc)
            .find(this.&isEven)
}

@CompileStatic
private void groovyFuncWithMethodReference(int n) {
    // does not work
    // org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    // ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 15: The argument is a method reference, but the parameter type is not a functional interface
    def res = (1..n).collect(this::calc)
            .find(this::isEven)
}

@CompileStatic
private void streamFuncWithMethodReference(int n) {
    // works
    def res = (1..n).stream()
            .map(this::calc)
            .filter(this::isEven)
            .findFirst()
}

int calc(int x){
    return 2*x+1
}

boolean isEven(int x){
    return x % 2 == 0
}
```

Comment: With `@CompileStatic` enabled, the compiler will look for a functional interface when given a method reference.
You can force what I presume you are expecting with something like this:
`(1..n).collect((Closure)this::calc).find((Closure)this::isEven)`

Comment: I don't know about this specifically, but CompileStatic is kinda useless because of how many things aren't supported. In my opinion, unless you have some very time dependent code that you want to optimise heavily, leave CompileStatic alone.